# Why is non-qualified template function's instance without angle brackets can't be friend of class?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>

class foo;
template<typename T> void bar(T a) { std::cout<< a.var; }

class foo { 
    int var;
    public: 
      friend void bar(foo); //here, bar function template is declared in global namescope,
      // deduction can deduce which template instance we're talking about. 
      //Note: If I place <> just after name bar or qualify bar like ::bar , it all works then.
};

int main() {
    foo fooo;
    bar(fooo);
}
```

error: /home/O1wLF2/cc1xOI20.o: In function 'main': prog.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to 'bar(foo)'

What I want to know why non-qualified template function's instance can't be friend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a non-template function a friend. You need yo tell the compiler that you want to make a template a friend or one of the instantiations.

Comment: I disagree with you , try to run the same program including just qualifying `bar` like `::bar` without even using <> (http://www.ideone.com/cZ6jA) in MSVS , it will run fine.

Comment: The friend declaration in the class declares a non-template function named bar() and taking a foo objects as parameter. This has nothing to with the function template declared (and defined) above. Well, it is an overload of the function template which is preferred when the argument types match exactly. If you explicitly qualify bar() it can't be a declaration and, apparently, finds the function template. Two different things, though.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis : I don't know what exactly that code is supposed to prove or disprove, but [this](http://ideone.com/C4B9L) is the code you need to be looking at.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Now that comment of your made sense to me. ThankYou :)